# overflow hidden for list items

Tags: html, css, html-lists, overflow

I have a UL list which has images in li. I have given UL width as 400px, if the li items are more then i want it to be hidden but it is coming in next line. Any solution?

Here is my demo
http://jsfiddle.net/vtuRL/8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set an additional `white-space: nowrap;` to you `UL`-list to prevent a line break at the end of the available space.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/vtuRL/10/

Answer (score 0):

Overflow hidden is only allowed on BLOCK elements. You can't set UL as block. But here's an example on how it could work:

http://jsfiddle.net/vtuRL/9/

Just added

```
.p_gallery { float:left; width:400px; overflow:hidden; }
```

And changed the ul CSS

```
.p_gallery ul{ margin:20px 0 20px 24px; background-color:#ccc;  padding:0; float:left; width:1000px;}
```

Comment: You are answering on false assumptions: the `overflow: hidden;` value may be set on any element and of course an `UL` can be set to `display: block;` (which is the default, btw).

Comment: Sorry, I was of the opinion that ul is no block element. But my answer works. And why doesn't overflow: hidden work, only with nowrap?

Comment: It also works without `white-space: nowrap;`, but you need to set a height, which wasn't in the given example. Without specifying a height of the parent box, the `overflow: hidden;` still works, but the box is expanded in the height to stretch around all wrapped elements.